# How to get tables from postgresql in heroku?

Tags: windows, postgresql, heroku, pgadmin, git-bash

I have windows, git bash,pg-admin 3, a Heroku app with a PostgreSQL database,Is there any git bash command to get the db and tables name? because i forgot the names and i can not make any query (select * from (?) )

I have tried:
\list command in git bash, but does not exist.
Looking from Heroku web but no success.
Is there any way to get the names?

Comment: `select * from information_schema.tables` http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/information-schema.html

Comment: wow, thx, i got all info there! now i know the names of my tables! (not from git bash, using heroku webpage).
can i see the columns of that tables?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*git bash* is simply a *Cygwin*-esque *bash* emulator that allows *git* to be run under Windows. Just as there is no native *bash* command to interact with *Postgres*, neither would there be one for *git bash*. You would need a separate program in either case.

*Heroku* has a special version of the regular *Postgres psql* called **pg:psql**  which will let you run queries on the tables in your *Heroku Postgres* instance.

So you could run, for example:

```
SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY id;
```

More info on this tool is available here:

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#pg-psql

More info on *Postgres psql* here:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/app-psql.html

Comment: Ok!that was the reason of several error messages.  
thanks so much!!

Comment: Sure, no problem. Since it appears this answered your question, please accept my answer. More details on how to do that (among other info) can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: they changed command slightly in 2020, open cmd in windows and type `heroku pg:psql -a <app_name>` and then you can type SQL

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned by [the user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/330315/a-horse-with-no-name)

```
heroku pg:psql

select * from information_schema.tables;
```